# Use the trapezoidal rule with n = 4 to find $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}$ cos x dx. Estimate the maximum error in your calculation.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

(i) Use the trapezoidal rule with n = 4 to find $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}$ cos x dx.

**(i) My attempt**

I got my step size to be $\frac{\pi}{16}$  and my values for $x_0$,=0, $x_1$=$\frac{\pi}{16}$, $x_2$=$\frac{\pi}{8}$, $x_3$=$\frac{3\pi}{16}$ and $x_4$= $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

I then subbed these values in for x into Cos x to get my y-values. I subbed my y-values into the formula $T_n$= $\frac{1}{2}$h ($y_0$ +2$y_1$+2$y_2$...$y_n$) and I got $\approx$ 0.7048335513.
I am happy with this answer. It is (ii) where I am confused.

(ii)Estimate the maximum error in your calculation. We have used |${E_T}{_n}$|≤ $\frac{1}{12}$(b - a)$h^2$M to get the error for trapezoidal rule.

**(ii) My workings so far**

$\frac{1}{12}$(b-a)=$\frac{\pi}{48}$

$h^2$ = ($\frac{\pi}{16}$)$^2$= 0.03855314219

M= f ''(x)= -cos x.

Max value = - cos ($\frac{\pi}{4}$)=  - 0.7071067812.

Am I right so far? I am unsure where to go from here.

Comment: What is stopping you from simply using: $$|\text{error}|\le\frac{M}{12N^2}(b-a)^3$$

Comment: Because that is not the formula my lecturer uses.

Comment: So $M=1$ because the second derivative of $\cos$ is $-\cos$, which is again between $-1$ and $1$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop are you not meant to sub in 0 and ($\frac{\pi}{4}$) to see which gives a max value?

Comment: @artefact191 Your formula and my formula are the same since $h=\frac{b-a}{N}$

Comment: You've got all the pieces... you have $M=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, you have $h=\frac{\pi}{16}$. $|\text{error}|\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{\pi/4-0}{12}\frac{\pi^2}{16^2}$And you can clean that up

Comment: Hm actually your $M$ is incorrect. $M=1$ is the maximum

Comment: how did you get 1 as the maximum? You are meant to check it at 0 and ($\frac{\pi}{4}$), neither of these values give 1?

Comment: @artefact191 we first need to know *what* we need, and only then *how* to get it. As $M$ is the maximum of the modulus of the second derivative, first find this second derivative. It is $-\cos x$. On $[0,\pi/4]$ its modulus is $\cos x$. When does that function reach its maximum? It *happens* to be monotonically decreasing, so it reaches the maximum at $0$ and the maximum is $1$. If it wasn't a monotonic function, then you would need to use some more advanced technique than just checking its value at the ends of the interval.

Comment: that is great. thank you so much!